# How can i upload image using yammer API

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, yammer

I want to upload image using yammer api: 
Ref: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/upload-files-into-yammer-groups,
 https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post

```
function CheckIamge() {

    var yammerFile = $('input[name=yamCreatePostFile]')[0].files[0];

    var file_data = new FormData();
    file_data.append('network_id', '123456');
    file_data.append('target_type', 'GROUP');
    file_data.append('filename', yammerFile.name);
    file_data.append('file', yammerFile);
    file_data.append('group_id', '13078');

    yam.platform.request({
       url: "https://filesng.yammer.com/v4/uploadSmallFile",
        data: file_data,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', BC_YammerAuthoring.tokenToSend) },
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
       // mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: "multipart/form-data", //'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8'
        processData: false,
      //  dataType: 'json',
        method: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("ajax post success.", data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error("File upload Error -", err);
        }
    });
}
```

Error : "Error: 500 Server Error,HTTP error 500 - Problem accessing v4/uploadSmallFile, Reason: "Server
Error". 
File size is less than 4MB.

It would be very helpful if anyone can help me in uploading file issue.
Thank you.

Comment: See my answer for PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062985/how-to-upload-files-on-yammer-api-via-the-azure-upload-small-file-api/66062986#66062986