# How to upload files on Yammer API via the Azure Upload Small File API

Tags: php, file-upload, guzzle, yammer, yammer-api

## How to upload an attachment along with a Yammer message?

Any legacy method through `attachment1` etc. fields of the  `/messages.json` endpoint won't work anymore.

The new method is not so well documented: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/upload-files-into-yammer-groups

I'm giving here an example in PHP below, but you can do the same in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You have to do it in two part

1. First upload the picture to https://filesng.yammer.com/v4/uploadSmallFile and get the picture's id.
2. Send your message as usual to https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json along with the freshly got picture id.

*Note: I will use here the [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) library for the REST calls.*

### 1. Send the picture to the Azure cloud

```
protected function yammerFileUpload(string $file, string $filename): int
{
    $multipart = [
        [
            'name'      => 'network_id',
            'contents'  => $this->networkId,
        ],
        [
            'name'      => 'group_id',
            'contents'  => $this->groupId,
        ],
        [
            'name'      => 'target_type',
            'contents'  => 'GROUP',
        ],
        [
            'name'      => 'filename',
            'contents'  => $filename,
        ],
        [
            'name'      => 'file',
            'contents'  => $file,
            'filename'  => $filename,
            'headers'   => ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']
        ],
    ];

    $client = new Client();

    $options = [
        'headers'       => [
            'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $this->yammerToken",
        ],
        'multipart'     => $multipart,
    ];
  
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://filesng.yammer.com/v4/uploadSmallFile', $options);

    return \json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true)['id'];
}
```

Of course, you have to replace class variables with your owns. And the **content type** by your file's one.

### 2. Send your message

```
public function postMessage(string $message, string $file): array
{
    $fileId = $this->yammerFileUpload($file, 'my-file.jpg');

    $client = new Client();

    $options = [
        'headers'   => [
            'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $this->token",
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'body'               => $message,
            'group_id'           => $this->groupId,
            'attached_objects[]' => "uploaded_file:$fileId",
        ],
    ];

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json', $options);

    return \json_decode((string)$response->getBody(), true);
}
```

Comment: This is great, Erdal, thanks for sharing. How did you obtain an access token? It appears an AAD access token is needed, and the developer token won't work. Did you use a browser-based oauth flow?

Comment: OK I figured something else out. Some Yammer networks use SharePoint for file storage and some do not. The ones that do not, the old developer token will still work.

Comment: @DerekGusoff Indeed I used OAuth flow user side (and then server access), according to the doc you have to do browser authentication anyway. Then I just used the bearer Token I've got from APIs, and it worked.